# How to select the set of points that are real from the a txt file?

Tags: import

I have the following txt file. Each line (except for the first line 100 and blank line) in the txt file is a point with its real and imaginary parts. For example, the points presented in the file are

$(1.004786849932060−01+∗1.093556972652714+00),(−1.004786849932060−01+∗−1.093556972652714+00),(9.976096134274947−20+∗−1.192941404973469−19),(−1.480297485865874+00+∗7.422776004582909−02),...$

```
100    

1.004786849932060e-01 1.093556972652714e+00
-1.004786849932060e-01 -1.093556972652714e+00
9.976096134274947e-20 -1.192941404973469e-19
-1.480297485865874e+00 7.422776004582909e-02
-1.480297485865874e+00 7.422776004582909e-02
-1.000000000000000e+00 -5.551115123125783e-17

-8.393828623433014e-01 -8.910743549375130e-02
8.393828623433014e-01 8.910743549375130e-02
-2.564013936414357e-21 -4.714327574115172e-23
5.664048419599507e-01 -1.320526392429827e-01
5.664048419599508e-01 -1.320526392429827e-01
-1.000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000e+00

-1.000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000e+00
-0.999000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000e+00
-1.000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000e+00
-1.000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000e+00
-1.000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000e+00
-1.000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000e+00
```

My question is how to select the blocks that all 6 numbers are real (with adjusted threshold), so that the code should output

```
{-1.000000000000000e+00+0.000000000000000e+00 I,
    -0.999000000000000e+00+0.000000000000000e+00 I,
    -1.000000000000000e+00+0.000000000000000e+00 I,
    -1.000000000000000e+00+0.000000000000000e+00 I,
    -1.000000000000000e+00+0.000000000000000e+00 I,
    -1.000000000000000e+00+0.000000000000000e+00 I}
```

Thanks advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

With your data in `/tmp/data.txt`, then:

```
(Import["/tmp/data.txt", "Table"] /. {} -> Nothing)[[2 ;;, 1]]
```

yields:

```
{0.100479, -0.100479, 9.9761*10^-20, -1.4803, 
-1.4803, -1., -0.839383, 0.839383, 
-2.56401*10^-21, 0.566405, 0.566405, -1., -1.18278, 
1.18278, 5.69358*10^-20, -2.49179, -2.49179, -1.}
```

`/. {} -> Nothing` gets rid of the empty lines, and `[[2;;,1]]` selects the first column from each row starting with row two.

OK, edited for the clarified question.

Split data into groups by the blank lines:

```
data = SplitBy[
Import["/tmp/data.txt", "Table"][[2 ;;]], # == {} &] /. {{}} -> 
Nothing;
```

Convert pairs to complex numbers:

```
cdata = Map[# . {1, I} &, data, {2}];
```

Select blocks where all imaginary parts are zero:

```
 Select[cdata, And @@ Map[Im[#] == 0 &, #] &]
```

yielding:

```
{{-1. + 0. I, -0.999 + 0. I, -1. + 0. I, 
-1. + 0. I, -1. + 0. I, -1. + 0. I}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but the output does not match. The first point $1.004786849932060e-01 1.093556972652714e+00$ is not real. It has imaginary part $1.093556972652714e+00$.

Comment: @HJ_dynamics I thought you wanted the real parts.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I want the block (which contains 6 points) that all the 6 points are real.

Comment: @HJ_dynamics I'm still confused, then. The revised data in your post has a block of 4, not 6, that you are asking for.

Comment: ah sorry!!  I just revised again!

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear whether you want a more semantic selection (block of all Reals) or a formal selection (block that matches a string pattern). The output you say you want is not typical Mathematica form, so you'd have to create a special string representation. But even then the excessive runs of 0 and the 00 exponents seem weirdly superfluous. So, here's an attempt and maybe you can modify to suit your actual need.

```
data = Import[pathToFile, "Lines"]; (*gives list of strings*)

blockData = SequenceSplit[data, {""}]; (*creates blocks by splitting on empty string*)

complexPairBlocks = Map[Interpreter["Number"], StringSplit /@ blockData, {-1}];
(*turns each string to a number so that we can handle them in the
 semantic domain of Real and Complex numbers*)

complexNumberBlocks = Map[#[[1]] + I #[[2]] &, complexPairBlocks, {-2}];
(*creates actual Complex numbers from the pairs*)

complexNumberBlocksChopped = Chop[complexNumberBlocks];
(*since you're looking for numbers with zero imaginary part, we can
 just chop everything in preparation for a subsequent filter*)

Select[complexNumberBlocksChopped, FreeQ[_Complex]];
(*we select the block that has no Complex numbers in it (because the
 near-zero imaginary parts were chopped to 0 leaving reals)*)
```

The result of this is

```
{{-1., -0.999, -1., -1., -1., -1.}}
```

Which isn't the form that you said you want, but it matches the semantics of what you seem to want. You could create a display/string form for numbers that adds back in all of the 0 and e and I. You would map that display function over the results.

Answer (score 2):

Read the file as numbers, ignoring the `100`. `Chop` and  then make `Complex` numbers in blocks of six each.

```
data3 = ReadList["C:/test2.txt", Number]

data4 = data3 // Rest // Partition[#, 2] & // Chop // 
   Complex @@@ # & // Partition[#, 6] &
```

Check to see which row has all six `_Real` numbers:

```
Dimensions[data4]
Position[data4, {Repeated[_Real, {6}]}]
```

> `{{3}}`

To get these:

```
Cases[data4, {Repeated[_Real, {6}]}]
```

> ```
> {{-1., -0.999, -1., -1., -1., -1.}}
> ```

The format you have adopted for your desired output is not Mathematica friendly. When a number has a head `_Real`, it does not have the `I` part.